# saving ccf() looped output in r

Tags: r, time-series, cross-correlation

I have a df where the first little bit looks like:

```
>dput(df_long_binned_sound2[1:48,])
structure(list(id = c(20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 
20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 
20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230420, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 20230424, 
20230424, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 
20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 20230426, 
20230426, 20230426), cons_id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L), win = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), sound = c(1, NA, 1.5, 
NA, 2, NA, 2.75, NA, 7, NA, 8, NA, 4, NA, 6.5, NA, NA, 4.5, NA, 
6, NA, 2, NA, 5.5, NA, 4.66666666666667, NA, 4.8, NA, 6, NA, 
4.5, NA, 3, NA, 2.33333333333333, NA, 6, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1.66666666666667, 
NA, 4.5, NA, 5), sound2 = c(NA, 1, NA, 1.5, NA, 1.5, NA, 6, NA, 
8, NA, 1, NA, 8, NA, 7, 3, NA, 5, NA, 5, NA, 5, NA, 6.5, NA, 
8, NA, 6, NA, 5, NA, 5.66666666666667, NA, 3.5, NA, 2, NA, 2.42857142857143, 
NA, 1.5, NA, 2, NA, 8, NA, 2.33333333333333, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am running some cross-correlation analysis on it and I would like to save the number outputs of `ccf()`. I can save all the correlograms using:

```
ids <- unique(df_long_binned_sound2$id)
for (i in 1:length(ids)){
  pdf(file = paste("/Users/myname/Desktop/Current Work/CRTT study - 2022/CRTT - Full/CRTT_r_Full/Wack_A_Mole/CC_CustomBin/CC/plot_", ids[i], ".pdf"),
      width = 10, height = 10
  )
  
  ccf(df_long_binned_sound2$sound[which(df_long_binned_sound2$id == ids[i])], df_long_binned_sound2$sound2[which(df_long_binned_sound2$id == ids[i])],
      na.action = na.pass,
      main = paste("Corrected Correlogram \n Pair", ids[i]),
      xlim = c(-6, 6)
  )
  
  dev.off()
}
```

and I can print the number outputs using:

```
for (i in 1:length(ids)){
  print(ccf(df_long_binned_sound2$sound[which(df_long_binned_sound2$id == ids[i])], 
                     df_long_binned_sound2$sound2[which(df_long_binned_sound2$id == ids[i])],
                     na.action = na.pass,
    )
  )
}
```

I would like to save the number outputs so that I end up with something like:

| id | lag | lag_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20230420 | -9 | -0.145 |
| 20230420 | -8 | -0.057 |

...

| id | lag | lag_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20230420 | 8 | -0.183 |
| 20230420 | 9 | -0.203 |
| 20230424 | -9 | 0.234 |

...

I'm sure there is a simple solution but I can't seem to find it. I very optimistically tried and failed with:

```
df.cff <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(ids)){
  cff.standin <- ccf(df_long_binned_sound2$sound[which(df_long_binned_sound2$id == ids[i])], 
      df_long_binned_sound2$sound2[which(df_long_binned_sound2$id == ids[i])],
      na.action = na.pass,
    )
  df.cff <- cbind(df.cff, cff.standin)
}

Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"acf"’ to a data.frame
```

and:

```
df.cff <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(ids)){
  cff.standin <- ccf(df_long_binned_sound2$sound[which(df_long_binned_sound2$id == ids[i])], 
      df_long_binned_sound2$sound2[which(df_long_binned_sound2$id == ids[i])],
      na.action = na.pass,
    )
  df.cff <- rbind(df.cff, cff.standin)
}

Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length
```

Does anyone know a good way to save the number outputs of `ccf()` from a for loop? I am especially interested in a solution that formats the output like the table examples above.

TYIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inspect the `ccf` object with `View()` or checking it's help page:

> **Value**
>
> An object of class "acf", which is a list with the following
> elements:
>
> *lag*  A three dimensional array containing the lags at which the acf is
> estimated.
>
> *acf*  An array with the same dimensions as lag containing the estimated
> acf.

Thus, you just want to do something like:

```
cbind(id = ids[i], lag = cff.standin$lag, lag_value = cff.standin$acf)
```

Now for the full solution:

```
ids <- unique(df_long_binned_sound2$id)
df_ccf <- c() #empty vector to save results
for (i in ids){ #you can pass the ids directly, instead of their index
  df1_subset <- df_long_binned_sound2[which(df_long_binned_sound2$id == i),] #saving an extra variable saves space in the call below
  
  ccf_output <- ccf(df1_subset$sound, df1_subset$sound2,
                    na.action = na.pass,
                    main = paste("Corrected Correlogram \n Pair", i),
                    xlim = c(-6, 6)
  )
  
  df_ccf <- rbind(df_ccf, cbind(id = i, lag = ccf_output$lag, lag_value = ccf_output$acf)) #iteratively rbind the results
}
```

But I prefer something using *tidyverse*:

```
df_ccf <- df_long_binned_sound2 %>%
  group_split(id) %>%
  imap_dfr(function(data, index){
    ccf(data$sound, data$sound2,
        na.action = na.pass,
        main = paste("Corrected Correlogram \n Pair", i),
        xlim = c(-6, 6)) %>%
      {tibble(id = ids[index],
              lag = as.numeric(.$lag),
              lag_value = as.numeric(.$acf))}
  })
```